# @ColumnTransformer no está funcionando correctamente

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Lo que estoy intentando es **leer datos en una consulta**(read) y **escribir en una columna**(write) llamada **endoso**, que es una propiedad, para que la base de datos pueda persistirla, ya que esta propiedad está calculada y quiero que se muestre en la base de datos. Pero me está fallando al ejecutar mi programa. ¿Alguien sabe lo que podría estar pasando?

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "remesa_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Remesa remesa;
     
private Long endoso;

@ColumnTransformer(read = "(select count(*)"
+ " from Documento"
+ " inner join Remesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = Documento.remesa.id"
+ " inner join EnvioRemesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = EnvioRemesa.remesa.id"
+ " where Remesa.id=remesa.id)" //remesa.id is the id of the property remesa
, write = "endoso = ?" )
private Long writeEndosoInDataBase;
```

No sé si es la nomenclatura ideal la que estoy usando , o debería hacerlo en otro sitio.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir de qué modo no te funciona? Si tienes una excepción, si no persiste los datos o si no obtiene correctamente los datos pero no muestra errores...

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner una anotación `@Column(name = "endoso")` y en `write` escribir simplemente un `"?"`?

Comment: No te entiendo! @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro del problema que tienes, pero en los ejemplos que encuentro el uso de esta anotación se parece más a

```java
@Column(name="endoso")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "(select count(*)"
+ " from Documento"
+ " inner join Remesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = Documento.remesa.id"
+ " inner join EnvioRemesa"
+ " on Remesa.id = EnvioRemesa.remesa.id"
+ " where Remesa.id=remesa.id)" //remesa.id is the id of the property remesa
, write = "?" )
private Long writeEndosoInDataBase;
```

Comment: Se me queda a null la columna "endoso" , osea se crea la columna , pero con datos nulos , de la forma que me has dicho. Y no es problema de la query ya que la he probado en oracle y va bien. A no ser que ese "remesa.id" no lo esté interpretando bien en hibernate

Comment: Aun así he probado un caso simple y tampoco se inserta nada